# Why no call fstab64 after read? And can this be a problem?

Tags: c, linux, strace, lib

I want to create a new dynamic library instead of another, the source code of which is lost. I have created a library with exported functions, but the program does not load it. Conclusion Strace is almost the same, the only difference is that in the case of loading my library after the call to read() there is no call to fstat64().

strace original library:

```
open("/usr/local/lpr/li2/libSA.so", O_RDONLY) = 12
read(12, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\3409\0"...,     1024) = 1024
fstat64(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=46166, ...}) = 0
old_mmap(NULL, 40256, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE, 12, 0) = 0x40150000
mprotect(0x40159000, 3392, PROT_NONE)   = 0
old_mmap(0x40159000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, 12, 0x8000) = 0x40159000
close(12)                               = 0
```

my library:

```
open("/usr/local/lpr/li2/libSA.so", O_RDONLY) = 12
read(12, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\210\0\0"...,     1024) = 1024
close(12)                               = 0
time(NULL)
```

Comment: Are you linking with your library or loading it with `dlopen`?

Comment: load with 'dlopen'

Comment: Then do `dlopen` fail or succeed? If it fails, with what error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to load a 64-bit shared object into a 32-bit process.

The [ELF header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) read by these two `read()` calls:

```
read(12, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\3409\0"...,     1024) = 1024
```

and

```
read(12, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\210\0\0"...,     1024) = 1024
```

differ.  Note that the fifth byte in the first `read()` is `1`.  That's the **successful** load of a 32-bit shared object.

That fifth byte is `2` on the **unsuccessful** attempt - and that `2` means that the shared object is a 64-bit shared object.

You likely need to compile and link with the `-m32` option.